# Appending a "delete link" to cloned elements with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

All,

I need to add a "delete" link to the end of all of my cloned sections, but not the source of the cloned material. [This is what I have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/castonzo/yuuC8/)

Need something like this:

**Step One:**

[image]

**Step Two:(The cloned material does not get a delete link)**

[image]

```
 <html>
    <head>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>Demo</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var uniqueId = 1;
    $(function() {
         $('.addRow').click(function() {

             var copy = $("#cosponsors").clone(true).appendTo("#myForm");
             var cosponsorDivId = 'cosponsors_' + uniqueId;
             copy.attr('id', cosponsorDivId );

             $('#myForm div:last').find('input').each(function(){
                $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + '_'+ uniqueId); 
                $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + '_'+ uniqueId); 

             });

             uniqueId++;  
         });
    });
    </script>


    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
        <h3>Sponsors</h3>
        <form action="" id="myForm">
          <div id="cosponsors" style="padding:12px;">
            <label>Sponsor Info:</label> <input  type="text" id="cosponsorcontact" name="cosponsorcontact"  placeholder="Name" title="Co-sponsor contact" />
            <input  type="text" id="cosponsoremail"  name="cosponsoremail"     placeholder="Email" title="Co-sponsor email" />
            <input  type="text" id="cosponsorphone"  name="cosponsorphone"     placeholder="Phone" title="Co-sponsor phone" />
          </div>
         </form>


        <input type="button" class="addRow" value="Add Sponsor" />

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var deleteLink = $("<a>delete</a>");
 deleteLink.appendTo(copy);
 deleteLink.click(function(){
     copy.remove();
 });
```

Note that you'll need to style the delete link appropriately since it doesn't have an href.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5QBLB/

Comment: Missing `>` in the delete link - you must have copied it in the 20 seconds before I edited my answer ;-)